# How to use pip 1.5 (on Python) to install and later upgrade externally hosted package repositories?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Let us take the example of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-dom-xpath. In this case the package repository is hosted in http://code.google.com/p/py-dom-xpath/.

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

> pip install py-dom-xpath

```
Downloading/unpacking py-dom-xpath
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement py-dom-xpath
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external py-dom-xpath to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for py-dom-xpath
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\insrkum\pip\pip.log
```

> pip install --allow-external py-dom-xpath

```
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

> pip install --allow-all-external py-dom-xpath

```
Downloading/unpacking py-dom-xpath
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement py-dom-xpath
  Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified py-dom-xpath to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for py-dom-xpath
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\insrkum\pip\pip.log
```

I attempted use --index-url option without any success. What works is the following command

> pip install http://py-dom-xpath.googlecode.com/files/py-dom-xpath-0.1.tar.gz

This is not the best way to install externally hosted package repositories. I am interested to use --allow-external or --allow-all-external.
I also want to learn how to use --upgrade option with externally hosted package repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Pip 1.5 is safe : you need `--allow-external` to download externally hosted packages
and `--allow-unverified` to download from "http" sites.

You can do it with

```
pip install --allow-all-external --allow-unverified py-dom-xpath py-dom-xpath
```

and

```
pip install --allow-all-external --allow-unverified py-dom-xpath py-dom-xpath --upgrade
```

Comment: don't use `--allow-all-external` when you want to allow only one and not all.

Answer (score 0):

Both `--allow-unverified` and `--allow-external` take package name as an argument.

```
From pip help install:
--allow-external <package>   Allow the installation of a package even if it
                             is externally hosted
--allow-unverified <package> Allow the installation of a package even if it 
                             is hosted in an insecure and unverifiable way
```

- `--allow-external` requires an argument (name of th external to allow).
- Same goes for `--allow-unverified` too .
- With `pip install --allow-external pyodbc`, you are allowing the external called `pyodbc`
- `pip install --allow-external pyodbc pydodbc` is what you need, first `pyodbc` allows that external, second one actually tells pip which package to install.

  From pip help install:
  --allow-external    Allow the installation of a package even if it
                               is externally hosted
  --allow-unverified  Allow the installation of a package even if it 
                               is hosted in an insecure and unverifiable way

So your usage should be

`pip install <pkg> --allow-unverified <pkg> --allow-external <pkg>`

or the little confusing:

`pip install --allow-unverified <pkg> --allow-external <pkg> <pkg>`

***DO NOT*** use `--allow-all-external` when you just want to allow one and not ***ALL***. It kills the whole purpose of putting in the security check.